# nginx to expose internal http service as https subdomain

Tags: http, authentication, https, nginx, subdomain

I have found several partial answers on this site and similar ones, but I couldn't figure out how to put them together, or maybe the answer is there and I cannot recognise it :-/

What I'm trying to achieve:

I have an http service running in the LAN (I have setup dnsmasq appropriately) as:

http://subdomain1.domain.com:1234/

and I would like to expose it as internet (also the external DNS is working fine):

https://subdomain2.domain.com:443/

with user authentication handled by nginx.

I also want to (must?) keep the URL visible in the browser unmodified.

I have tried several combinations of what I found from similar questions, but something seems to elude me.

This is my last attempt:

```
ssl_certificate /var/www/domain.com/domain_com.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /var/www/domain.com/domain_com.key;

server {
        listen   443 default_server;
        server_name subdomain1.domain.com;

        location / {
                auth_basic "Restricted";
                auth_basic_user_file /var/www/domain.com/domain.com.passwords;

                proxy_pass              http://subdomain1.domain.com:1234/;
                proxy_set_header        Host    $http_host;
                # proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
                # proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_redirect          https://subdomain2.domain.com/       http://subdomain1.domain.me:1234/;
        }
}
```

What I get is: "Error 107 (net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR): SSL protocol error."

---

Update:

I think I found a solution, but review would still be appreciated.
This one also rewrites http access to go through https.

```
ssl_certificate /var/www/domain.com/domain_com.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /var/www/domain.com/domain_com.key;

server {
        listen   80;
        server_name subdomain1.domain.com;
        rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
        listen   443;
        ssl on;
        server_name subdomain1.domain.com;

        location / {
                auth_basic "Restricted";
                auth_basic_user_file /var/www/domain.com/domain.com.passwords;

                proxy_pass              http://subdomain2.domain.com:1234/;
                proxy_set_header        Host    $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto       $scheme;
                add_header              Front-End-Https         on;
                proxy_redirect          off;
        }
}
```